# Como fazer a conversão correta do IPAddress.Parse

Tags: c#, socket

Olá, estou fazendo uma comunicação com um equipamento utilizando socket.
Estou utilizando a biblioteca `System.Net` para fazer a conversão do ip e passando a porta como parâmetro no `IPEndPoint` para usar na `SocketEquipamento.Connect`

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.000.077");
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
SocketEquipamento.Connect(remoteEP);
Console.WriteLine("Conectado com sucesso");
```

Desse forma `192.168.000.077` o `IPAddress.Parse` está convertendo para o `ipAddress` o seguinte resultado `192.168.0.63`

Se passar o ip `192.168.0.77` ele mantem o ip e faz a conexão.

Gostaria de saber o por que ele está fazendo isso quando passa `192.168.000.077`.

Existe uma outra forma de fazer essa conversão? Ou devo ter fazer um tratamento na hora de receber o ip tirando os `0` a esquerdas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um número com zeros à esquerda é um número octal, isto é, um número escrito na base 8.
Assim,

```
(octal) 077 = (decimal) (0 x 64) + (7 x 8) + (7 x 1) = 63
```

Em outras palavras, de maneira geral evite escrever números com zeros à esquerda.

Comment: Tem alguma função já  `System.Net` que faz essa verificação?  Se não tiver tem algum exemplo de tratamento nesse caso?

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta...mas o que deve fazer é **não** usar zeros à esquerda: `IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.77");`

Comment: Sim eu entendi que devo usar  `192.168.0.77` , porem eu preciso retirar esses zero por que o ip e dinâmico eu passei fixo na pergunta só para ficar mais claro o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: se você está lendo esses números de um arquivo de configuração, então de maneira geral você também **não** deve usar números com zeros à esquerda no arquivo de configuração

Comment: Esta vindo de um banco de dados, preciso de uma função que tira esses zeros, você conhece alguma? Eu pensei em usar o `Replace` porem vai retirar todos os zeros.

Comment: eu não trabalho com C#,  mas imagino que você pode testar se o campo é todo preenchido com zeros, neste caso você substitui com apenas um zero...no outro caso imagino que o Replace deve ser suficiente...fora isso não posso ajudar, pois não tenho experiência com C#

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver criando um método que faz isso.